# How to restrict visibility of differential in phabricator without diffusion?

Tags: phabricator

I have two separate teams using the same Phabricator instance.  But due to the nature of team A's work team B are not permitted access to their code.
Is it possible to restrict access to particular revisions without using diffusion repositories?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please got through the link on how to ask effective questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It looks like it's possible to use the default view policy option to restrict initial visibility however, when I set this to Subscribers, no one is able to create a diff.

Comment: Hi David, I am facing the same issue here, were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: Not for the default view policy no, I'm currently having to import the repos and use the diffusion permission inheritance "feature".  It's less than ideal.